# How to reference objects in xcode 4 storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

In the storyboard I dragged over a viewcontroller (B) so that the storyboard now contains two viewcontrollers... B and the original (A).
I put a button on A and dragged it to B to make a button click on A bring up B.
On B I dragged a label and a button.
I want to click the button on B to make the label on B show "hello world".
How do I procede?

Comment: I'm not sure how much luck you'll get finding answers to iOS 5 related questions on SO as it's still under NDA and therefore is prohibited to be talked about publicly. If you are a member of the iOS Developer Program you are actually breaking your contract by posting this question here. You'd be better off posting in the iOS 5 specific forum over on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).

Comment: Please don't flag all iOS 5 questions for moderation due to iOS 5 currently being in beta. We (as in the collective members of SO) has not signed any NDA so we're not bound by any such agreement. There is no way we can know about all such NDA's in effect, when they end, who they're for, etc. and in any case, *we're not liable unless we ourselves have signed the NDA*. If @Sheldon wants to risk his membership status by breaking his NDA, it's up to him. For all we know he hasn't signed the NDA either and came by the information 2ndhand. I agree with the forums, but enough flags already.

Comment: I'll certainly take your points on board, but this is the **first time** I've flagged something for discussing iOS 5 so take a little offence to the tone of your final statement. As for @sheldon, only people signed up to the iOS Developer Program have access to the version of Xcode containing the features he's discussing and is therefore in direct violation of the NDA he's agreed to abide by before downloading said software. However, as you've stated it's entirely his decision whether or not he wishes to risk his membership.

Comment: You need to be on the Apple forums for developers only if you're going to be asking questions related to Apple Confidential stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you are member of iOS program, then look for video from **Session 309** of WWDC 2011 called '*Instroducing Interface Builder Storyboarding*'.